# IKEv2 with PSK on Windows Server 2012

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012-r2

Is it possible to configure Windows Server 2012 to run an IKEv2 VPN with a preshared key?  It *appears* to be possible in the general IKEv2 protocol, and it *appears* to be supported by the actual checkboxes in Windows Server 2012, but my attempts to connect are failing, and nothing on the internet tells me how to make it work.

I've attached what my screens look like below.  When I try to log in, my client gets an authentication failure.  Have I configured my server correctly to use a PSK with IKEv2?  Is there some straightforward way to change the configuration?  Thanks

I've setup a PSK:

[image]

I'm not sure how the "Allow custom IPsec Policy" checkbox interacts with the settings on the "Authentication Methods" screen, but here is what's there:

[image]